# Proper treatment of Carmichael numbers in exponents

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, carmichael-numbers

Let $C=\prod (q_i),\ q_i \in \mathbb P$ be a Carmichael number. It is further true of Carmichael numbers that they have at least three prime factors and are square free, i.e all $q_i$ are distinct. For any positive integer $a$ coprime to $C$, $a^{(C-1)}\equiv 1 \bmod C$. Moreover, by Euler's theorem, $a^{\phi (C)}\equiv 1 \bmod C$, where $\phi(n)$ represents the totient function of $n$. For Carmichael numbers, $\phi (C)=\prod (q_i-1)$. So for Carmichael numbers $$a^{(\prod (q_i)-1)}\equiv a^{(\prod (q_i-1))}\equiv 1 \bmod C$$
I was considering whether it would be possible to test whether a number is a semiprime by the evaluating relationships of the form $a^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1 \bmod pq,\ p,q \in \mathbb P$, and I realized that I did not know (and so far have been unable to prove to myself one way or the other) whether such a test would be compromised if one or both of $p,q$ were Carmichael numbers, much as Carmichael numbers in isolation compromise primality testing by Fermat's little theorem.

**Question:** In the simplest case, for an exponent $pC$, I know that $a^{\phi (pC)}\equiv 1 \bmod (pC)$, but is it also the case that $a^{(p-1)(C-1)}\equiv 1 \bmod (pC)$?

If so, one can imagine exponents having a large number of prime factors could be treated (for some purposes) as if they contained fewer factors by accumulating some of the prime factors into one or more Carmichael numbers.

**Added by edit:** I have performed some calculations using the Carmichael number $C=1105=5\cdot 13\cdot 17$ and the prime $p=7$, yielding the exponent $pC=7735$. For each of $a=2,3,11$ it seems that $a^{(p-1)(C-1)}\equiv a^{\phi(pC)}\equiv 1 \bmod 7735$. So Carmichael numbers as factors of an exponent **can** compromise a test for semiprimes based on $a^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1 \bmod pq$.

My choice of $1105$ was predicated on the fact that $1103$ is prime, and I was interested in whether such a test could be applied to twin prime candidates. So a result that $a^{(1103-1)(1105-1)}\equiv 1 \bmod (1103\cdot 1105)$ does not indicate that $1103,1105$ are twin primes, a fact that would be otherwise obvious in this particular instance because $1105$ is plainly divisible by $5$ and not prime. The example was chosen to test the method, not this particular case.

Comment: Do you know this criterion : A squarefree odd composite number $\ n\ $ is a Carmichael number, if and only if $\ p-1\mid n-1\ $ holds for every prime factor $\ p\ $ of $\ n\ $ ?

Comment: @Peter I know that. In my case, that means each $(q_i-1)\mid (C-1)$. But that does not mean that $(C-1)=\prod (q_i-1)$, so I remain a bit uncertain as to what conclusions to draw about $(C-1)$ when it appears in the exponent in conjunction with other prime factors.

Comment: If $p\nmid C$ and $\gcd(a,pC)=1$, then $a^{(p-1)(C-1)}=\bigl(a^{p-1}\bigr)^{C-1}\equiv 1^{C-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ and $a^{(p-1)(C-1)}\equiv\bigl(a^{C-1}\bigr)^{p-1}\equiv 1^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{C}$, thus $a^{(p-1)(C-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{pC}$. In essence, your test uses the ordinary Fermat test, which is vulnerable to Carmichael numbers. You can make it less vulnerable by using the stronger test like in the Miller–Rabin test. But, to get the exponent $(p-1)(C-1)$ you need to have the factorisation $p\cdot C$ anyway, so to check whether $pC$ is a semiprime, it's natural to test $p$ and $C$ for primality.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer This question was the first step in a larger (now invalid) scheme to attack the twin prime conjecture. Twin primes $p,q=6m\pm 1$ have a semiprime product $pq=36m^2-1$, and $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)=36m^2-12m$. I was hoping to look at $a^{36m^2-12m}\bmod (36m^2-1)$ which can be run through looking only at $m$ without having to determine independently whether $6m\pm 1$ are prime. But since Carmichael numbers can masquerade as primes in this scheme, I will have to abandon this line of thought.